# Remove system menu buttons

Tags: winapi

The situation is simple. Is it possible somehow, with the usual means of the Win32 API, to leave only two buttons in the system menu (minimize and close)?

Visually, I want to achieve the following result:

[image]

But it only turns out like this:

[image]

Perhaps you can try to do a trick and replace the[?] button icon:

[image]

Comment: `The last image link looks more like a dialog box than a window. The first link looks like you need a custom title bar.`

Comment: Only by drawing and handling the caption yourself I think. Not easy but possible.

Comment: Seems like as soon as you add the `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` style, then the maximize box is already added (albeit disabled). I tried all sorts of combinations but can't get there...

Comment: Okay, but what about replacing the button icon? for example the one in the third picture?

Comment: It doesn't matter which window. The option in the third picture is very similar to what I want. And if we make one amendment, namely change the picture, then this will visually solve my question.

Comment: There is no simple API to achieve this requirement. You need to draw the title bar yourself. Refer to: [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmgetwindowattribute). And you should use `DwmGetWindowAttribute` with `DWMWA_CAPTION_BUTTON_BOUNDS` flag then draw your title bar.

Comment: Dwm is cool. What about the windows version where this is not supported?